# How to enable autocomplete PyGTK symbols in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, pygtk, ropemacs

I have installed ropemacs in emacs and do [these instructions](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=edit&file=faq23.043.htp):

> 1. Edit config of the rope project (using M-x rope-project-config or directly opening .ropeproject/config.py) and replace the line
>
>    prefs['extension_modules'] = []
>
>    with
>
>    prefs['extension_modules'] = ['gtk._gtk', 'gobject._gobject', 'pango', 'atk']
> 2. Remove file .ropeproject/globalnames from the root of your
>      rope project if there is one.

But it doesn't work. any idea to solve this problem?